# Escape String backslash using GSON

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson

I am trying to convert my hashmap to a JSON pretty print output.

I tried GSON and believe there is some issue with it handling string as inputs inside a map, is there any other way to do this?

```
Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap();
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().enableComplexMapKeySerialization().setPrettyPrinting().create();
                    map.put("Intro", Map_to_String);
                    map.put("Output", String_Val);
                    System.out.println(gson.toJson(map));
```

Output:

```
{
  "Intro": {\"No\":0,\"Cast\":2},
  "Output": "123"
}
```

Required Output:

```
{
  "Intro": {"No":0,"Cast":2},
  "Output": "123"
}
```

Comment: `{"Intro": "{"No":0,"Cast":2}","Output": "123"}` - is invalid `JSON`. Are you sure you do not want to `{"Intro": {"No": 0,"Cast": 2},"Output": "123"}` as in my answer?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I ll update the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to deserialise `Map_to_String` back to object - `Map` in this case and after that serialise again.

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class GsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .enableComplexMapKeySerialization()
                .setPrettyPrinting()
                .create();

        String jsonString = "{\"No\":0,\"Cast\":2}";

        Type mapType = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>() {}.getType();
        map.put("Intro", gson.fromJson(jsonString, mapType));
        map.put("Output", "123");
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(map));
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
{
  "Intro": {
    "No": "0",
    "Cast": "2"
  },
  "Output": "123"
}
```

Comment: My actual data also has string values (Non numeric) in the keys "No" and "Cast", could you let me know the changes required in such a case? If I change the TypeToken to <String,Object> then the output I am getting is converting Integer's to decimal. I would like the output to be in String format itself (Non decimals).

Comment: @InheritedGeek, in that case you should use `Map<String, String>` type. It will automatically use `String` for values.